# How to access component method in React from a WebSocket callback

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a problem with Javascript and React. I want to change a components state based on push messages from a WebSocket.

My problem is that I do not know how to call the the function `handlePushMessage` from the WebSocket callback. Here is the code:

```
const MainPage = React.createClass({
    ...
    componentDidMount: function() {    
        var connection = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:12345');
        connection.onmessage = function (e) {
            var jsonData = JSON.parse(e.data);
            handlePushMessage(jsonData);
        };
    },

    handlePushMessage: function(data) {
        ...
    }
}
```

I have tried different syntaxes for specifying that function and I tried accessing the function via `this`. However nothing has helped. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using that (save this before the callback):

```
const MainPage = React.createClass({
    ...
    componentDidMount: function() {    
        const connection = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:12345');
        const that = this;
        connection.onmessage = function (e) {
            const jsonData = JSON.parse(e.data);
            that.handlePushMessage(jsonData);
        };
    },

    handlePushMessage: function(data) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Explanation: while in the callback, *this* refers to the connection object and not to the class you created.

A working jsFiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/esnuxz81/3/

Answer (score 1):

This should work too:

```
const MainPage = React.createClass({
    ...
    componentDidMount: function() {    
        var connection = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:12345');
        connection.onmessage = this.handlePushMessage;
    },

    handlePushMessage: function(e) {
        var jsonData = JSON.parse(e.data);
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could consider switching to à "flux" pattern. Where you "persist" data into stores then connect your stores to your components (through react-redoux for example). This way, your components are agnostic of the service layer, all that matters is their props no matter where they come from.